# PostSharp TFS build error : license not installed

Tags: postsharp

been using PostSharp for 6 months now, just the Essentials part, no problems with local or TFS online builds, then this started to happen:

```
D:\a\1\s\ACME.Email.Publisher\ACME.Email.Publisher.csproj : error PS0242: License error. No valid license key has been installed. Please visit https://www.postsharp.net/purchase to acquire a license of PostSharp. To register a license key, use PostSharp Essentials or start the evaluation period, execute the program C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\5.0.44\bin.Release\PostSharp.Settings.UI.exe.
C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\postsharp\5.0.44\build\PostSharp.targets(314,5): error : The process C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\5.0.44\bin.Release\postsharp-net40-x86-native.exe exited with code 11. [D:\a\1\s\ACME.Email.Publisher\ACME.Email.Publisher.csproj]
Build FAILED.
```

So...I've read the post sharp support page. Looks like their heuristics check for running in unattended mode  - and thus not enforcing licensing -is now failing. Following their suggestions :

1. I've set up an environment variable like so: Environment.UserInteractive = false
2. I've printed the PID of the process running the build. It is 0 (although I don't have much control over that).
3. They suggest adding the license key to the build, I don't have one.
4. 1-3 did not help so they suggest letting customer support know by using stack overflow and so here I am.

Comment: Your query is about PostSharp license, not about TFS ans msbuild. The issue can not be fixed by TFS or msbuild. I'll remove tfs and msbuild tags.

Comment: PostSharp writes the diagnostic messages for the unattended mode detection into the build log. You can try to rebuild your project with the diagnostic MSBuild verbosity and look for these messages. Maybe there were some changes in the recent TFS online version that broke the unattended mode detection.